# How to use jquery insertBefore to append only once?

Tags: jquery

I need to add heading to my Table , so once the table is created i am doing it this way

```
$( "<p>ONEHTML</p>" ).insertBefore( "#one");
```

But the issue i am facing is that it is being appended multiple times

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/23/

Comment: why are you keeping it in click event ? if you dont want to add it multiple times. place it on load

Comment: You are doing two things here. One, adding a header column to the table and two, adding a paragraph `<p>ONEHTML</p>`. Both are added by you in the code. So, what is the issue here?

Comment: change your html, wrap the table with a `div` and give `id` which you gave to table and place the `p` tag directly there. instead of dynamically adding.
`<div id="one"><table id="one" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">  
      </table></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean it's being appended more than once when it's clicked more than once? I would just put a `<div class='t_head'></div>`, and on click of that button, I would do `$('.t_head').html("ONEHTML")`. Or something along the lines of that so its changing the HTML inside of the div and the clicks after that wont do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your html as below to achieve the output you are expecting. From your HTML and Javascript I am Guessing that you are trying to achieve tab functionality. Try this if it suits your needs.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/28/)

```js
$("ul.tabs-2 li").click(function() {
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if (tabclicked === '#one') {
        $(".tabContent").hide();
        if($("#one").find("p").length === 0){
            $("#one").prepend("<p>ONE HTML</p>");
        }
        var onehtml = '<thead><th>ONE</th></thead>';
        $("#one").show().find("table").html(onehtml);
    } else if (tabclicked === '#two') {
        $(".tabContent").hide();
        if($("#two").find("p").length === 0){
            $("#two").prepend("<p>TWO HTML</p>");
        }
        var twohtml = '<thead><th>TWO</th></thead>';
        $("#two").show().find("table").html(twohtml);
    }
});

$('ul.tabs-2 li:eq(0)').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divforhistoricresults" class="classhistoricaldataresults">
  <div class="list-container-2">
    <ul class="tabs-2 clearfix">
      <li class='default'><a href="#one">Data</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Chart</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-container-2">
    <div id="one" class="tabContent">      
      <table class="tab-content-1 table table-striped"></table>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="tabContent">
      <table class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">                        
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the heading is dynamic.

Comment: you mean `<p>ONE HTML<p>` is dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.is()` within `if` conditions

```
 && !$("p").is(function() {
      return $(this).next("#one").length
    })
```

to addend `p` element only if next element is not `#one` or `#two`

```js
$("ul.tabs-2 li").click(function() {
  var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if (tabclicked === '#one' && !$("p").is(function() {
    return $(this).next("#one").length
  })) {
    var onehtml = '<thead><th>ONE</th>';
    $("#one").show().html(onehtml);
    $("#two").hide();

    $("<p>ONEHTML</p>").insertBefore("#one");

  } else if (tabclicked === '#two' && !$("p").is(function() {
    return $(this).next("#two").length
  })) {
    var twohtml = '<thead><th>TWO</th>';
    $("#two").show().html(twohtml);
    $("#one").hide();

    $("<p>TWO HTML</p>").insertBefore("#two");
  }
});

$('ul.tabs-2 li:eq(0)').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divforhistoricresults" class="classhistoricaldataresults">
  <div class="list-container-2">
    <ul class="tabs-2 clearfix">
      <li class='default'><a href="#one">Data</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#two">Chart</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-container-2">
    <table id="one" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">
    </table>
    <table id="two" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SusheelSingh _"Its not working perfectly please check"_ ? Can describe details ?

Comment: @SusheelSingh _"its like a tab when one displays other one should hide."_ Where is this affect described at Question ? See OP at _"But the issue i am facing is that it is being appended multiple times"_